# Drop Down Form for Date is Deformed

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I use sharepoint 2010 and I get a deformed pop up menu for Date selection. Nothing fancy here. Just a simple form to enter some data with date. 
Have you seen this before? I get the same effect in Chrome/Firefox latest versions.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your SharePoint site's CSS (or possibly with JavaScript that affects the CSS).

That big image is a spritesheet; CSS is supposed to crop the visible region so that you only see the specific sprites that are relevant to the current control.

You can pull up the developer tools with F12 and inspect the image element and its containers to see what CSS is currently applied, as well as check for any errors in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Thank you,but sigh.., this is a default installation of sharepoint 2010 and I have not modified any of the css files. Sometimes, but just sitting down and writing an app from scratch takes less time than trying to implement the same thing in sharepoint...

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browsers cache and reload page. Delete the datetime column and create a new.